# Redirect page without file extension in Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I am developing a web site. I'm facing a problem. I gave all file name like test.php but I want when it loads in browser it should be httt://mydomain/test

Right now I'm redirecting the page by javascript:

```
      window.location = "./foldername/test.php";
```

by PHP:

```
      header('Location: ./foldername/test.php');
```

How can I do this without .htaccess file because in project I don't have this file.Thanks in advance.

Comment: in their you want to tell filename as a foldername  ok or not

Comment: It's a folder name. I just want to remove last file name extension from the url when it loads in browser.

Comment: as said by @priya786 just name a directory as your file and put the file inside named index.php

Comment: yes you can solve it make a filename as folder and in it save the file as index.php

Comment: Thanaks @priya786, but I have many files inside that folder I want all url for corresponding file name like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use preg match to find the filename parameter from url and then include that file with extension append to it...

preg_match('@[/]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@', $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"], $matches)

This wll give all the parameters of the url. Just use the second parameter which will be your filename. Add extension to it and include that dynamically.

Comment: Please explain me in details how can I redirect page dynamically without extension.

Comment: Follow this link http://www.dangibbs.co.uk/journal/php-url-rewriting-without-apache-and-mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, this how you can strip a file's basename from a path.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getFilename(string,include_extension){

    //  Looks for a forwardslash followed by a valid filename followed by a dot and then a valid file extention
    var matches = string.match(/\/\w+\.[a-z]{3,4}/)

    if( matches.length ){
        //  Strips off starting slash and file extension
        var my_filename_without_extention = matches[0].replace(/(^\/|\.\w+$)/g,'')
        //  Strips off starting slash only
        var my_filename_with_extention = matches[0].replace(/^\//g,'')
    }else{
        return false
    }

    if(include_extension)   return my_filename_with_extention;

    return my_filename_without_extention
}

alert( getFilename(window.location.href,true) )

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @FactoryAidan But How can I redirect page by this . If I'm using this in ajax response redirect page.

Comment: I do not require file name without extension I just want to remove last extension from the URL only. so that It will be more readable.

Comment: With the filename stripped off, you can set your location to any combination you want with that filename.  So if someone lands on the page at yourdoman.com/yourfile.php, you can load the new page with the function above in javascript by setting window.location='/'+getFilename(window.location.href,false);
That would send you to yourdoman.com/yourfile/
Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: OHHH, you mean you need url rewrites!  This can only be done on your web server configuration.  Whether it is Apache or Nginx or any other web server.  Rewrites can only be set in .htaccess or by setting your web server to send all url requests to a handler.  It is not possible to clean up and rewrite urls with only php or javascript.